# $(document).height and $(window).height both return the same value - proper doctype in use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on setting up a floating action button, like in Google's new Material Design. This is the jQuery I'm using right now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var doc = $(document).height();
    var height = $(window).height();
    var offset = height - 20 ;
    console.log(doc);
    console.log(height);
    console.log(offset);
    $("#floating_nav_container").css("top",""+ offset +"px");   
});
```

I want to be able to detect the height of the viewport and have my action button display 20px above the bottom.

My "floating_nav_container" is an absolute positioned div within a bootstrap "col-md-6" parent div that I've set a fixed height for testing purposes of 900px.

Sometimes the `$(document).height()` gets the 900 right, and other times it doesn't; the `$(window).height` is always the same as the document one.

My doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

which I've read on here is the usual fix when these two methods return the same value.

EDIT: I'm trying to accomplish this within a 3 column layout. The "floating_nav_container" is only applicable to the middle column. Setting it's CSS to fixed position with a bottom of 20px doesn't work because depending on the viewport size the action button might show on the third column or outside of the columns altogether.

If the "floating_nav_container" is set as fixed with the code set for it to be a child of the middle column it behaves the same as if it was set up at the top of the DOM.

I've opted for having it absolutely positioned within the middle column because then no matter how the browser is re-sized it stays within the parent container. The problem is when the page runs beyond the height of the viewport the button is gone.

My hope is to find a way to calculate the height and have it dynamically determine what the offset from the bottom of the viewport should be for any device.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with this problem? Because in the console this returns two different numbers. So I find it hard to reproduce this problem. Or maybe an url?

Comment: @JasonvanderZeeuw thanks for the reply!

I have a fiddle of it built here 

https://jsfiddle.net/m3wh2g74/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that worked best for me using some of the proposed solutions here. In case anyone else comes across a similar problem in the future here is everything I did that got it to work the simplest.

I moved the "#floating_nav_container" out of the middle column so that it wasn't a child of anything.

The CSS on the "#floating_nav_container" is this:

```
#floating_nav_container {
position:fixed;
bottom:20px;
right:40px;
z-index:10;
}
```

This gets it positioned properly for mobile use, but doesn't keep the button within the middle column once the design is scaled to desktop size.

To ensure that the button always stays within the middle column I used media queries to set it's "right" to 31%.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #floating_nav_container {
    right:31%;
  }
}
```

My layout is made with bootstrap and the 3rd column is a "col-md-3" which is always 25% of the available width of the viewport. By setting my right on the "#floating_nav_container" to 31% I've enabled it to always stay tucked inside the middle column as the design scales.

Once the right column is dropped and only the middle column remains then the default css for the "#floating_nav_container" kicks in and handles the display.

This completely eliminated my need to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Move the #floating_nav_container outside of the parent div, and use @floribon's solution.  Also if you want it to always be 20px from the bottom, even when scrolling set the position to fixed.

```
#floating_nav_container{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:20px;
}
```

I've added a fiddle here for you https://jsfiddle.net/9v9u8ybp/

Comment: thanks!

I had it set that way to begin with but it was giving me an undesirable display on the desktop, my layout is 3 columns and only the middle is interactive, I want the "floating_nav_container" to behave as if it's fixed  but within the middle column.
@NickDelaney

Comment: That fiddle look good! Is there anyway to add another column of content and have the "floating_nav_container" always be fixed within it?

Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out with this! @NickDelaney

Comment: @MikerT I've updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9v9u8ybp/3/  .  It's using jquery like you were originally doing.

Comment: Yes! That looks perfect, thanks a million for helping out with this! @NickDelaney

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it fully in CSS to prevent any bug:

```
#floating_nav_container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @floribon!

I have the CSS like that right now (while testing the function i've commented out my bottom) but that puts it 20px from the bottom of the parent div and it's then hidden from view on the screen

Comment: then do you really need it as a child of its parent? Couldn't you put this element higher in your DOM?

Comment: I only have it as a child of the parent because when I'm using the site in desktop view the layout is 3 columns, the middle column is the one with the interactive content so I want to try and keep the action button within the parent column so it doesn't confuse people.

If I put it first in the DOM and make the position fixed, it always stays where I want when the screen is at mobile size...but when i re-size to desktop it's not pretty @floribon

Answer (score 0):

For viewport-aware positioning of elements, use CSS instead of jQuery or js like this:

```
#floating_nav_container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```